# Multiple iterators on JDBC resultset

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I've built a graph in a database as a table - each record is an edge (The graph is just too huge to store in memory) . Now I'm trying to do transitive reduction on the graph . For this I query the table and repeatedly compare each record (3 at a time) for a certain condition ([wiki of transitive reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction))

So I project the whole table into a resultset . Now I need three iterators to point to different points in the Resultset so that I don't have to keep 3 seperate resultsets for each loop. Can it be done in java? The next method in result set gives me only one iterator. Is there a way for me to keep track of three records at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A result set permits only one iterator.

For best performance you should do as much work as possible with SQL queries instead of iterating result sets. For example PostgreSQL, which you seem to be, using permits [queries on the transitive closure using `WITH RECURSIVE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).